# Как считать файл *.yml в dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, yaml, dataclass

Допустим у меня есть .yaml файл, упрощенно так:

```
oracle:
    user_name : name
    password: password
yandex:
    api_key: xxxxx
    params:
        param1: 1
        param2: two
```

И есть описанные классы:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Oracle:
    user_name: str
    password: str


@dataclass
class Params:
    param1: int
    param2: str


@dataclass
class Yandex:
    api_key: str
    params : Params

@dataclass
class Config:
   oracle: Oracle
   yandex: Yandex
```

Сейчас для чтения всех параметров используется упрощенно такой код:

```
def get_config(config_file='config.yaml'): 
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    full_file_path = os.path.join(here, config_file)
    with open(full_file_path, 'r') as yaml_file:
        config = yaml.load(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
    params = Params(param1= config['yandex']['params']['param1'], ...)
    yandex = ...
    oracle = ...
    return Config(oracle, yandex)
```

Не покидает ощущение, что это можно оптимизировать так, чтобы считывать параметры буквально в пару строк и сразу грузить в классы. Но ничего похожего найти/придумать не могу.

Подскажите, что тут можно сделать?

Comment: `params = Params(**config['yandex']['params'])` - это? Или вы о другом?

Comment: Я хочу считать вообще все в класс Config не создавая каждый подкласс по отдельно. Ваш вариант частично упрощает, но мне хотелось бы вообще вычитать )

Comment: В таком случае написать конструктор для `Config` все же придется, потому что он не хранит никакой информации о типах своих полей и не знает, что их надо создавать, а не просто присвоить значения позиционных или именованных аргументов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой *yamldataclassconfig* (`pip install yamldataclassconfig`).
Она накладывает чуть больше ограничений на объявление класса, зато потом менять конфигурацию одно удововольствие. Подбронее почитать по [ссылке](https://pypi.org/project/yamldataclassconfig/).

Код вместо лишних слов:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin
from yamldataclassconfig.config import YamlDataClassConfig


@dataclass
class Oracle(DataClassJsonMixin):
    user_name: str = None
    password: str = None


@dataclass
class Params(DataClassJsonMixin):
    param1: int = None
    param2: str = None


@dataclass
class Yandex(DataClassJsonMixin):
    api_key: str = None
    params: Params = None


@dataclass
class Config(YamlDataClassConfig):
    oracle: Oracle = None
    yandex: Yandex = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Config()
    config.load()
    print(config)
```